# How to pass POST body data to another route without losing the data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, body-parser

Let us assume that i have this route

```
 app.post('/category',function(req,res){
    res.redirect('/category/item');
 })
```

The user is going to post some data in this route and then is going to be redirected automatically to another route for an example `/category/item` to post another data

So at the end i want to collect those two post's data the one in route `/category` and the other one in route `/category/item` to query my database.

Comment: hmm. Why do you need two routes here? Why can't you skip the redirect and just place the next handler after that one?

Answer (score 2):

Using [express session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) is the best choice to save the first posted data and then get those data in the second request, here is an example:

**add session middleware**

```
const express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    session = require('express-session');

// use session middleware
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
}));
```

**Store data in session**

```
app.post('/category', function (req, res) {
    // store posted data in the session
    req.session.category = req.body;

    res.redirect('/category/item');
});

app.post('/category/item', function (req, res) {

    // force users to deal with /category first
    if ( !req.session.category ) {
        return res.redirect('/category');
    }

    // get data from the session
    var category = req.session.category;

    // req.body contains the second submited data
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `http` status code `307` which indicates that the request should be repeated using the same method and post data.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect(307, '/category/item');
});
```

Which will preserve the send data.

For reference, the 307 http code spec is:

> 307 Temporary Redirect (since HTTP/1.1) In this occasion, the request
>   should be repeated with another URI, but future requests can still use
>   the original URI.2 In contrast to 303, the request method should not
>   be changed when reissuing the original request. For instance, a POST
>   request must be repeated using another POST request.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store the data from the first call either in memory (a variable) or in your database. HTTP is a completely stateless protocol, so there will be no way to communicate across that boundary (one request to another). I'd recommend storing the data in your DB, perhaps in a temporary hold table, then syncing it up after the second request is made.

```
app.post('/category',function(req, res){
  // store data from req.body in a temporary table in your DB
  // be sure to key it with something that will tie it to future requests
  // such as a userId, sessionId, etc

  res.redirect('/category/item');
});

app.post('/category/item',function(req, res){
  // find existing data from the temporary DB table using some key
  // like the userId, sessionId, etc

  // then add take the new data from req.body, merge it with the data 
  // from the temporary table above, and store it in the final 
  // location in the DB
});
```